# How do I create a very simple webhook?

Tags: javascript, php

First off, go easy on me. While I have been doing extremely basic coding since I was a child, it's only been over the last few months that I started getting into the real stuff like Java, Javascript, PHP/MySQL, etc. So please bear with me if I use wrong terminology or write something that sounds completely wrong. I'd love to get some insight from all you tireless helpers here.

Here is what I need:

- I have a website at myserver.com.
- I want to use the `API` at `randomsite.com` to automate a process.
- If I manually go to the URL `randomsite.com?do=this`, my process will be triggered.

What I want to be able to do is write an app on myserver.com that will trigger randomsite.com?do=this. Obviously I can have a link on my page, but the user will see that they have been directed to randomsite.com.

I do not need to capture anything about the `randomsite.com` link having been triggered. I don't care who clicked it, etc. All I want is to simulate the effects of going to `randomsite.com?do=this` but without actually opening that site on the front end.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If the site has an API, that's what you need.

Comment: @Sunyatasattva: He doesn't need to "have" their API, he just needs to "use" their API by calling it via URL. Are you thinking of an SDK?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to create a PHP script on myserver.com that can handle the request in the background to randomsite.com?do=this (using curl would be one reasonable way to do it). The question is tagged JavaScript, but there you have two problems. One, you'd be making a cross domain request, which brings in other issues, and second you can obfuscate, but not entirely hide the call from the user. By proxying the call from the myserver.com backend, you can avoid both these problems.

Comment: Just FYI Java and JavaScript have almost nothing to do with each other beyond the letters `j` `a` `v` `a`

Comment: It looks like curl is probably the way to go. I tagged this Javascript because I wasn't sure which tools would be best at solving this. Does anyone know of any good sites where I might be able to find a very basic "Hello World" type curl example? I see very extensive documentation at curl.haxx.se. It would be helpful to have something more basic to grasp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using AJAX for doing stuff behind the scenes...
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

EDIT: You would need to use JSONP for cross domain.

Comment: And that probably won't work because of cross-domain security restrictions.